# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable In Autotyper

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to create an autotyper that uses user input.
For the first line, the autotyper works as intended, but at the second line, there is an error. I wonder if it is because of the exception I made?

Here is my complete code:

```
import time
import random
from goto import with_goto

keyboard = Controller()
class label(Exception): pass

print('======Welcome to Autotyper v0.5 Currently still in development. We have a maximum of 4 lines, for bugs/suggestions email: alexanderhan00@gmail.com======')
while True:
    line1 = input("Please enter your first line:  ")
    line2 = input("Please enter your second line, type none if you don't have one:  ")
    if line2 == "none":
        break
    line3 = input("Please enter your third line, type none if you don't have one:  ")
    if line3 == "none":
        break
    line4 = input("Please enter your fourth line, This is the last line!!  ")
    break

hours = input("How many hours would you like to run this?     ")
retry = input("How long will it take until new message?(Seconds)     ")
timeout = round(time.time())
future = round(time.time()) + int(60)*int(60)*int(hours)
x = 5
print('Move cursor to target')
while x > 0:
    print(int(x)*'.')
    time.sleep(1)
    x = x-1
runs = 0

while True:
    random.seed()
    random1 = random.randint(0,10)
    for char in line1:
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    keyboard.press(Key.shift)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.shift)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    try:
        line2 = 1
    except NameError:
        break
    else:
        for char in line2:
            keyboard.press(char)
            keyboard.release(char)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    runs = runs + 1
    if timeout > future or runs == hours*60:
        break
    print("Random Seconds Added:")
    print(int(random1))
    print("Time to next entry:")
    for y in range(int(retry) + int(random1)):
        print(int(retry) + int(random1 - y))
        time.sleep(1)
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
Please enter your first line:  hi
Please enter your second line, type none if you don't have one:  none
How many hours would you like to run this?     1
How long will it take until new message?(Seconds)     10
Move cursor to target
.....
....
...
..
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\autotyper-random.py", line 49, in <module>
    for char in line2:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
hi
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks! I'm new to the community.

Comment: `line2 = 1` replaces the string with an integer. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: Instead of putting each input into a separate variable, put them all into a list. Then loop over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of this code:

```
try:
    line2 = 1
except NameError:
    break
else:
    for char in line2:
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

After `line2 = 1`, `line2` no longer contains the line that the user entered, it contains the integer `1`. `for char in line2` will no longer work because you can't loop over an integer.

I think you're trying to use that `try/except` block to tell if the user entered something for `line2`. But an assignment will never report a `NameError`, you can only get that error when trying to read a variable that hasn't been assigned yet. Also, the code that reads input always assigns to `line2`, so you won't get an error for it. The variables that might not be set are `line3` and `line4`, if you entered `none` for the previous lines.

Whenever you find your self creating variables with sequential names like this, you should probably be using a list instead of separate variables. Here's how you can read in all the input lines:

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input("Please enter your next line, type 'none' if you don't have one")
    if line == "none":
        break
    lines.append(line)
```

And when you want to type them out:

```
random.seed()
while time.time() < future and runs < hours*60:
    for line in lines:
        for char in line:
            keyboard.press(char)
            keyboard.release(char)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    runs += 1
    print("Random Seconds Added:")
    print(int(random1))
    print("Time to next entry:")
    for y in range(int(retry) + int(random1)):
        print(int(retry) + int(random1 - y))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Another problem is that you were never updating `timeout` during the loop, it's always the time that it started.